Could not build wheels for PyAudio on Nixos / issur with portaudio19-dev
I'm installing the requirements of my python script on Nixos, and getting this error :
ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyAudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

This can be solved on other distros by installing portaudio19-dev, but this specific package doesn't seem to be available on Nixos. And when I install portaudio, it doesn't solve the problem.
Where can I find the equivalent of portaudio19-dev on Nixos ?

Hi, first of all try updating setuptools, wheels and pip. And reinstalling package again. pip install --force-reinstall pip setuptools wheel. Then check that you have installed pyaudio using apt-install sudo apt install python3-pyaudio (following the manual).
